# How to send POST request with empty key and value as object in react native

Tags: react-native, post, fetch, postman

I'm trying to send request to get data but API needs value as an object and empty key (not null)

`Every post request must be sent as application/x-www-form-urlencoded And must send all the data through a single object. The key must be empty`

This is how i can send request via postman

```
POST: http://www.car.go.th/api/MobileApp/getModelCar
Headers: Key = Content-Type , Value = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body: Key = , Value = {"brand":"CHEVROLET","BodyType":"2040050811314debb706d02b33eca8e7"}
```

This is my react-native code

```
fetch('http://www.car.go.th/api/MobileApp/getModelCar', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                   '': { "brand": "CHEVROLET","BodyType":"2040050811314debb706d02b33eca8e7"}
            }),
        })
```

I got error response "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value" because API only accept empty key which my code have ' ' before :{"brand":"CHEVROLET"...}

Comment: As the body just send the literal string `brand=CHEVROLET&BodyType= 2040050811314debb706d02b33eca8e7`. That’s what `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data looks like: It’s just pairs of `foo=bar` joined by `&`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me check, Add your api in global

```
var postValues = {
            brand: "CHEVROLET",
            BodyType: 2040050811314debb706d02b33eca8e7
        }

    fetch(`${Global.APIUrl}`, {

        method: 'POST',

        body: JSON.stringify(postValues)

    }).then(res => res.json())

        .then(

            (result) => {

                 "YOUR CONDITIONS from result"
            }

        )
```

Comment: Thanks for answer
I tried your code but seems like you forgot to include header.
after I added header I got same error response